# Calculating transposes for elements of $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, linear-transformations, transpose

Here, $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ is the vector space of infinite sequences where only finitely many elements are nonzero. I could easily calculate this for a finite-dimensional vector space, but now when working with infinite dimensional vector spaces it has gotten really complex. I haven't formally learnt this and the summaries on other stack exchange posts and the wikipedia summary are quite confusing and seem to be very general. I was wondering if there is a nice way of calculating transposes for elements of $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb{R}^{\infty})$, which is hopefully simpler than the general case.

Comment: How is the transpose defined?

Comment: I assume as in the definition here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

For reference, this came up in the dual representation of Lie algebras, which I'm trying to work with. But the definition uses tranposes and I was trying to calculate the dual module of an infinite dimensional module.

Comment: The algebraic dual space of $\mathbb R^\infty$ is (algebraically isomorphic to) $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, the space of all real sequences. Given $a\in\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, the transpose of a linear $T : \mathbb R^\infty\to\mathbb R^\infty$ is given by $(T^*a)_j = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb^{(j)}_n$, where $b^{(j)} = Te_j$. Note that the sum is always finite as $b^{(j)}$ only has finitely many non-zero entries.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot